# Impossible to fix - absolutely can't get wsdl generated xml

Tags: php, xml, soap

This is getting ridiculous. I've been at this for 3 weeks in trying to get a wsdl generated xml, and I can't get anything.
I'm using PHP to generate the request.
The service description in this:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<s:element name="GetListaCategorii">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodClient" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Parola" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetListaCategoriiResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetListaCategoriiResult" type="tns:ListaCategorii"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ListaCategorii">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Nrreg" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Categorii" type="tns:ArrayOfCategorie"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfCategorie">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Categorie" nillable="true" type="tns:Categorie"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="Categorie">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Categorie" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="GetCatalog">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodClient" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Parola" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Categorie" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetCatalogResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetCatalogResult" type="tns:Catalog"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="Catalog">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Nrreg" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Produse" type="tns:ArrayOfProdus"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfProdus">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Produs" nillable="true" type="tns:Produs"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="Produs">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodProdus" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Denumire" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Categorie" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodProducator" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Producator" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Pret" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Moneda" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Instoc" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="hello">
<s:complexType/>
</s:element>
<s:element name="helloResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="helloResult"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetCatalogTot">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodClient" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Parola" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetCatalogTotResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetCatalogTotResult" type="tns:Catalog"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="GetListaCategoriiSoapIn">

<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetListaCategorii"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetListaCategoriiSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetListaCategoriiResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCatalogSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCatalog"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCatalogSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCatalogResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="helloSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:hello"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="helloSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:helloResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCatalogTotSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCatalogTot"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCatalogTotSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCatalogTotResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ZCatalogDistributionSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="GetListaCategorii">
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetListaCategoriiSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetListaCategoriiSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCatalog">
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetCatalogSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetCatalogSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="hello">
<wsdl:input message="tns:helloSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:helloSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCatalogTot">
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetCatalogTotSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetCatalogTotSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ZCatalogDistributionSoap" type="tns:ZCatalogDistributionSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetListaCategorii">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetListaCategorii" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCatalog">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetCatalog" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="hello">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/hello" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCatalogTot">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetCatalogTot" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="ZCatalogDistributionSoap12" type="tns:ZCatalogDistributionSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetListaCategorii">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetListaCategorii" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCatalog">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetCatalog" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="hello">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/hello" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCatalogTot">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetCatalogTot" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ZCatalogDistribution">
<wsdl:port name="ZCatalogDistributionSoap" binding="tns:ZCatalogDistributionSoap">
<soap:address location="http://exemple.com/service.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="ZCatalogDistributionSoap12" binding="tns:ZCatalogDistributionSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://exemple.com/service.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I'm trying to access the function `GetListaCategorii` with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
<body>
<?php  $client = new SoapClient("http://exemple.com/service.asmx?WSDL");
$listacateg = $client->GetListaCategorii(array("CodClient" =>  "my_code","Parola" => "Mypass"));
echo "<p>";
echo $listacateg->GetListaCategoriiResult->Nrreg;
echo "</p>";?>
</body>
</html>
```

The sample request should be :

```
POST /ZCatalogVB/ZCatalogDistribution.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: exemple.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetListaCategorii"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListaCategorii xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CodClient>string</CodClient>
      <Parola>string</Parola>
    </GetListaCategorii>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The respose should be

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListaCategoriiResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetListaCategoriiResult>
        <Nrreg>int</Nrreg>
        <Categorii>
          <Categorie>
            <Categorie>string</Categorie>
          </Categorie>
          <Categorie>
            <Categorie>string</Categorie>
          </Categorie>
        </Categorii>
      </GetListaCategoriiResult>
    </GetListaCategoriiResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please please help

the latest output

```
<pre><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:GetListaCategorii
><ns1:CodClient>mycode</ns1:CodClient>
<ns1:Parola>mypass</ns1:Parola>
</ns1:GetListaCategorii>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: For three weeks of trouble shooting you provide really very little information. The URI of the WSDL is invalid. Please provide a small but working example that demonstrates your issue. Also providing error messages and nicely formatting the XML might not be a too bad idea as well.

Comment: i wish i could but it will not do anathing because the damn thing is ip protected so only my ip can get access to the server

Comment: but any information is required i will provide it, no problem

Comment: i'm not a verry good with code as it shows :)

Comment: i'm absolutley desperate

Comment: as for an error message i get a "0" as a reply

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a print out of what your SOAP request looks like:
Post the result here so we can help you:

```
class mySoap extends SoapClient 
{
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) 
    {
        print_r('<pre>');
        print_r($request);
        die();

        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
    } 
}

$client = new mySoap("http://exemple.com/service.asmx?WSDL");
$params = new stdClass;
$params->CodClient = "my_code";
$params->Parola = "Mypass";
$listacateg = $client->GetListaCategorii($params);
```

try this one too and post the soap request envelope:

```
class mySoap extends SoapClient 
{
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) 
    {
        print_r('<pre>');
        print_r($request);
        die();

        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
    } 
}

$client = new mySoap("http://exemple.com/service.asmx?WSDL");
$params = new stdClass;
$params->CodClient = new SoapVar("CodClient", XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
$params->Parola = new SoapVar("Mypass", XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
$listacateg = $client->GetListaCategorii($params);
```

Comment: it just prints out usernamepassword

Comment: Please view source the result page to get the xml output.

As the xml will be interpreted by the browser, if you select view source you should get an the full xml of the request

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
<body>
<pre><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetListaCategorii><ns1:CodClient>my_code</ns1:CodClient><ns1:Parola>Mypass</ns1:Parola></ns1:GetListaCategorii></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: The envelope seems to be incomplete, can you try to add it again? OR add it to the question above inside of a code block

Comment: the sample output is in the question

Comment: Note: I added a second piece of code above. try it and post the output.

Comment: ok edited your response an added the output there, same as before

Comment: Is the output the same as before? it should contain some xsi:string
Please post the new output in a seperate post.

Comment: Damn this is getting hard to post :) the output is the same as before. Would you like to move this discution on mail or on skype/ yahoo messenger ?

Comment: Also i can give you shell access to my server in that way you could access the actual wsld site with the real user and pass

Comment: Ok, I was expecting something like this:
"<ns1:CodClient xsi:type = 'string'>CodClient</ns1:CodClient>" instead of "<ns1:CodClient xsi:type = 'string'>CodClient</ns1:CodClient>"
I am suspecting that the server does not understand the request because the types are missing in the request.

Are you sure there is nothing like that?

Comment: just updated the latest output, yap there is not type, but as it shows in the "sample request" the type is not preset there eighter

Comment: as the server is ip protected i'm trying to post a screenshot of the asmx page

Comment: Have you tested that the webservice works outside of php, using something like: SOAPUI (http://www.soapui.org/), this will give you a good idea of whether your webservice is working fine or not.

Comment: it is not my webservice, it is a parter's webservice, and i'm trying to get his data in xml for procesing reasons

Comment: just closed the phone with the partner and he assured me that the service is working fine and there are at lest 10 of his partners that uses the service on a daily basis

Comment: You should then talk to the webservice provider because your request envelope seems to be fine according to the images you attached.
Send them you request envelope and as them why you are not getting a reply.